# Grade Calculator isn't exiting

Tags: python, calculator, easygui

I have a program that is supposed to approximate  a letter grade based off of an integer input.  I want it to be able to run continuously until the number "-1" is input, then quit.  However, whenever I try to run it, the program just keeps telling me my grade over and over again, and it won't do anything else.  Here is what I have so far.

```
import easygui


grade = int(easygui.enterbox(msg="Enter a grade between 0 and 100: "))
while grade != -1:

    if grade >= 90 and grade <100:
        easygui.msgbox ("You got an A")
    if grade >= 80 and grade <90:
        easygui.msgbox ("You got a B")
    if grade >= 70 and grade <80:
        easygui.msgbox ("You got a C")
    if grade >= 60 and grade <70:
        easygui.msgbox ("You got a D")
    if grade >= 0 and grade <60:
        easygui.msgbox ("You got an F")

else: raise SystemExit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take the inputted grade again in while loop.

```
    import easygui


grade = int(easygui.enterbox(msg="Enter a grade between 0 and 100: "))
while grade != -1:

    if grade >= 90 and grade <100:
        easygui.msgbox ("You got an A")
    if grade >= 80 and grade <90:
        easygui.msgbox ("You got a B")
    if grade >= 70 and grade <80:
        easygui.msgbox ("You got a C")
    if grade >= 60 and grade <70:
        easygui.msgbox ("You got a D")
    if grade >= 0 and grade <60:
        easygui.msgbox ("You got an F")

    grade = int(easygui.enterbox(msg="Enter a grade between 0 and 100: "))

else: raise SystemExit
```

Comment: Although that added a cancel button, my problem is still not solved.  I want it to run continuously so as soon as it tells me the grade it prompts for another one.  Thank you though.

Comment: It works for me. So you don't even need to see the cancel button. You go on inputting the values. It will give you your grade. As you will enter -1, it will be closed.

Comment: are you on python 2 or 3?  I am running 2.7 and it is not working

Comment: I hope you are not missing the else : raise SystemExit part. I thought you will include it yourself

Comment: Say I entered the number 88.  It should say: "You got a B", and then prompt me to enter another grade between 0 and 100.  However, it just keeps saying: "You got a B", even when I click OK.

Comment: Yes, that worked.  Thank you so much.  I do not know the difference but obviously I screwed something up.  Huge help!

Answer (score 0):

```
import easygui
```

grade = int(easygui.enterbox(msg="Enter a grade between 0 and 100: "))
while grade != -1:

```
if grade >= 90 and grade <100:
    easygui.msgbox ("You got an A")
if grade >= 80 and grade <90:
    easygui.msgbox ("You got a B")
if grade >= 70 and grade <80:
    easygui.msgbox ("You got a C")
if grade >= 60 and grade <70:
    easygui.msgbox ("You got a D")
if grade >= 0 and grade <60:
    easygui.msgbox ("You got an F")

grade = int(easygui.enterbox(msg="Enter a grade between 0 and 100: "))
```

else: raise SystemExit